# Ajax calling .cshtml : 403 FORBIDDEN

Tags: asp.net, razor, http-status-code-403

I have AJAX call for .cshtml file and it keep saying it's 403 forbidden ... this is error I managed to pull out from Firebug ... using ASP.net app, framework 4 ... and I got no idea how to fix this, i tried most of things I found on net

Reset VS user, installing  Web platform .... I got no idea what to do next

Here is the error from firebug:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
       <title>This type of page is not served.</title>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
       <style>
            body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
            p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
            b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
            H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
            H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
            pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
           .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
           .version {color: gray;}
           .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
           .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }

     @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
           pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
     }
     @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
           pre { width: 280px; }
     }
    </style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="white">

        <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

        <h2> <i>This type of page is not served.</i> </h2></span>

        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

        <b> Description: </b>The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been
   explicitly forbidden. &nbsp;The extension '.cshtml' may be incorrect. &nbsp;&nbsp;Please review the
   URL below and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
        <br><br>

        <b> Requested URL: </b>/PopunjavanjeUpitnika/PopunjavanjeUpitnika/Upitnik.cshtml<br><br>


        <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

        <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version
   :4.0.30319.34280

        </font>

</body>
```

** EDIT: **

This is how I call the .cshtml file

```
function NavigateToPage(questionnaire_id, page_id, user_id, object_id) {
            $("#cont").load(
            "PopunjavanjeUpitnika/Upitnik.cshtml",
            { questionnnaireId: questionnaire_id,
                pageId: page_id,
                userId: user_id,
                objectId: object_id
            });
            throw new Error("Something went badly wrong!");
            return false;

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on cshtml extension I assume context is ASP.NET MVC project. If so then you should call action of controller which returns cshtml view instead of calling view file directly. That's basics of ASP.NET MVC and I would suggest you viewing http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview to be comfortable with it.

Comment: But thing is ... I am not making ASP.NET MVC project, it's just AJAX calling .cshtml file

Comment: You are not allowed to query cshtml files directly as that might cause source code disclosure. If you are 100% sure in that you need to query those then I would go with custom http handler that will accept cshtml filename and will return its content.

Comment: By the way, thank you for quick response! Also, me and friend are working on project, she made this on our project, and it works on her machine and not mine .. it's same project, same code ... is there any settings/permissions/ or something else that can keep this file from loading?